# Some bytes are missing after reading an std::ifstream to a vector of lines

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

For copying what I read from input file to vector, I used `std::copy()` as recommended in [Reading an std::ifstream to a vector of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675508/reading-an-stdifstream-to-a-vector-of-lines).

The problem occurs if I use:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(inputfile),
          std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(),
          std::back_inserter(myVector));
```

The 16th byte of my file is missing in the `myVector` variable.

But if I use the following code:

```
inputfile.read((char*)&myVector[0], sizeof(int)*getfilesize(nameOfFile));
```

Then the byte is not missing anymore.

I am trying to parse WAV files and I lost too much time on this, I hope I will learn something new out of this. Can you please tell me what is wrong with the first version of the code above?

Comment: The first version is using a formatted input function, thus skipping e.g. what it interprets as whitespaces.

Comment: Is the file opened in binary mode in both cases?

Comment: Yes , I didn't changed anything except above. I used ifstream like;     std::ifstream inputfile(nameOfFile.c_str(),std::ifstream::in|std::ifstream::binary);

Comment: Note also how the example you referenced deals with a file of "formatted" numbers, i.e. an integer represented as a sequence of (probably) ASCII characters, whereas the WAV file format contains a lot of binary representations.

Comment: Note IMO this `sizeof(int)*getfilesize(nameOfFile)` as the second argument of `read` is error-prone. Better use something like `myVector.size() * sizeof(myVector[0])`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`istream_iterator` uses `operator >>` to read elements, but `operator >>` skip whitespaces.

You may try using [`noskipws`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/noskipws/)

```
inputfile >> noskipws;
```

§ 24.6.1 p1. (my emphasis)

> The class template `istream_iterator` is an input iterator (24.2.3) that reads **(using operator>>)** successive
>   elements from the input stream for which it was constructed....

Comment: ... iff the skipws flag is set, which it is per default.

Comment: A better solution if you want to read binary bytes. might be to use `std::istreambuf_iterator`.

Answer (score 5):

Like RiaD said, `istream_iterator` performs formatted input via `operator >>`. The solution is to use unformatted reading on the underlying buffer. To do this, use `istreambuf_iterator`:

```
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputfile),
          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
          std::back_inserter(myVector));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `char` for the `std::ifstream`?

Comment: @DyP Right, I *always* make that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

First of all wav file is a binary data, so you should treat it as such, you should open your file in binary mode:

```
ifstream ifs;
ifs.open ("test.wav", ifstream::in | ifstream::binary);
```

Then, you have to use ordinary read function that works as you stated.

[ifstream documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/)